# Code Optimization, C code not Responding to Cache Blocking

Tags: c, performance, caching, optimization, processor

I'm working on a project in a class that has us optimizing C code. However, the server we are running the code on doesn't seem to respond well to usual optimization techniques or at least the ones that we have been taught. The assignment suggests using code motion, loop unrolling, and blocking.
Here are some of the structure definitions:

```
#ifndef _DEFS_H_
#define _DEFS_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

#define RIDX(i,j,n) ((i)*(n)+(j))

typedef struct {
  char *team;
  char *name1, *email1;
  char *name2, *email2;
} team_t;

extern team_t team;

typedef struct {
   unsigned short red;
   unsigned short green;
   unsigned short blue;
} pixel;

typedef void (*lab_test_func) (int, pixel*, pixel*);

void smooth(int, pixel *, pixel *);
void rotate(int, pixel *, pixel *);

void register_rotate_functions(void);
void register_smooth_functions(void);
void add_smooth_function(lab_test_func, char*);
void add_rotate_function(lab_test_func, char*);

#endif /* _DEFS_H_ */
```

Here is the function I'm currently working on it rotates an image 90 degrees:

```
char naive_rotate_descr[] = "naive_rotate: Naive baseline implementation";
void naive_rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        dst[RIDX(dim-1-j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
}
```

This is the baseline inefficient implementation.

```
char rotate_descr[] = "rotate: Current working version";
void rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int i, j;
    int ii, jj;
    int dim_min_one = dim - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i+=8){
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j+=8){
            for(ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++){
                for(jj = 0; jj < 8; jj+=8){
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+1), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+1), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+2), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+2), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+3), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+3), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+4), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+4), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+5), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+5), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+6), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+6), dim)];
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j+7), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj+7), dim)];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a combination of blocking and unrolling.

```
char rotate1_descr[] = "rotate1: Simple 16 blocking";
void rotate1(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int i, j;
    int ii, jj;
    int dim_min_one = dim - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i+=16){
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j+=16){
            for(ii = 0; ii < 16; ii++){
                for(jj = 0; jj < 16; jj++){
                    dst[RIDX(dim_min_one-(jj+j), (i+ii), dim)] = src[RIDX((i+ii), (j+jj), dim)];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is simply just blocking. 
Now the server the code is being tested on has 24 Intel(R) Xeon(R) X5660  @ 2.80GHz CPUs in it. The testing code gives a speed up of 1.2 for the blocking and unrolling loop, and a speed up of 1.4 for simple blocking.

On my own computer which is a Core i7 2.7GHz and the other school server which is 24 Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2420 at 1.9GHz the speed up for both the blocking and unrolling and just blocking is 1.9.

As well on all systems an 8 vs 16 block size don't seem to have a difference in performance, however, 32 will give a penalty to performance.

Now the other ES-2420 has 15mb of cache versus the X5660 which has 12mb, but I feel like this should not be enough to dwarf the effect of blocking that much or make unrolling reduce performance that much. I can't really find anything online that talks about optimizing for X5660 and techniques that it responds well to. So my question is what difference in processors would cause such a big difference in response to cache blocking and what can I take away from this difference to write code that will run better on it. The text book and lecture haven't really given me the tools to figure this out as all the techniques they suggest don't work well with the server we have to run it on.

Comment: You've left out the most important piece of information, which is the definition of `RIDX`. Since `RIDX` is called twice per pixel, that's the place to start your investigation, and if I'm correct you can rewrite the algorithm to completely eliminate `RIDX`.

Comment: What is the value of "dim"?  What type is "pixel"?

Comment: I added in the definitions, dim will be an int for the dimension of the square picture and will always be a multiple of 32.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/) on each machine, you can measure the cache miss rate and other interesting parameters to determine why you are getting different speedups on each one.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install software on the servers.